# mvc 5 asp.net controller if function is passing error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

here is I pass the correct user and password I will be able to get to new page but if it's wrong I get error:

this is the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Login(UserAccount user)
        {
            using (OurDbContext db = new OurDbContext())
            {
                var usr = db.userAccount.Single(u => u.Username == user.Username && u.Password == user.Password);
                if(usr != null)
                {
                    Session["UserID"] = usr.UserID.ToString();
                    Session["Username"] = usr.Username.ToString();
                    return RedirectToAction("LoggedIn");
                }else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Username or Password is wrong");
                }
            }
            return View();
        }
```

if I pass the wrong value I get error :

```
Line 49:             using (OurDbContext db = new OurDbContext())
Line 50:             {
Line 51:                 var usr = db.userAccount.Single(u => u.Username == user.Username && u.Password == user.Password);
Line 52:                 if(usr != null)
Line 53:                 {
```

Comment: Include the error details in your question.

Comment: you can see errors line by line, why I am getting down vote, here we come to learn

Comment: This site is to help the community. You have not included the details of the exception in your question (the actual error that is thrown) - all you have shown is the line of code which throw the exception

Comment: Ok, @StephenMuecke is this kind of login is correct, I mean login save session and authorize by session detail, is it secure?

Comment: @waliahmad That really is a separate question and one more suited to [http://codereview.stackexchange.com/](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: just a hint or instruction or yes no

Comment: No. There are multiple problems with your implementation. For a start, you never store passwords as plain text in a database (you hash and salt them). There is no point adding values to `Session` when your not even authenticating the user (by creating a `FormAuthenticationTicket`). I suggest you use Identity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Single`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535118(v=vs.110).aspx) will throw exception in this cases:

- `ArgumentNullException` source or predicate is null.
- `InvalidOperationException`
         **- No element satisfies the condition in predicate.** 
         - More than one element satisfies the condition in predicate.
         - The source sequence is empty.

Most likely, in your case the exception  will be thrown because there is no element which satisfies the condition.

So, you can consider to replace it with [`SingleOrDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549274(v=vs.110).aspx). It will return default value of the type in that case.

Comment: respected is this kind of login secure, thank you in advance

Comment: but now I am not able to see the error message(ModelState.AddModelError("", "Username or Password is wrong");

Comment: @waliahmad May be you have some other issues in your code. You can put breakpoint and debug your applicatoin if you wish.

Comment: yes but, my question is, is this kind of login secure, like login save session and give controllers and action authorization by sessions